# Get project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Output:

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

```
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Output:
The system cannot find the path specified.
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Output:
===================
# 1 "C:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/mingw81_32/mkspecs/features/data/macros.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "C:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/mingw81_32/mkspecs/features/data/macros.cpp"
QT_COMPILER_STDCXX = 201402L
# 26 "C:/Qt/Qt5.15.2/5.15.2/mingw81_32/mkspecs/features/data/macros.cpp"
QMAKE_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION = 8
QMAKE_GCC_MINOR_VERSION = 1
QMAKE_GCC_PATCH_VERSION = 0
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

For both 32 and 64bit version, and after a fresh installation.

Answer (score 1):

Reason could be your system might not have g++ installed or path to g++ is not set.

1. check g++ version
2. if version not found than install g++ compiler
3. Set PATH variable to g++ location . in linux g++ is in path - "/usr/bin/g++"
4. Try Setting below variables in qmake file

   ```
   QMAKE_CC = gcc
   QMAKE_CXX = g++
   ```

try compiling through command line :

```
qmake projectName.pro -r -spec linux-g++
```